# Как разделить промапленные элементы на 2 строки ReactJS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Подскажите пожалуйста что делать. Я получаю получаю элементы с бэка и с помощью .map() вставляю их. Мне нужно сделать что бы они делились на 2 равные колонки, но что бы я не делал, оно все время выглядит ужасно.
Я Задавал в стилях

1. Column: 2; (В Данном случае при уменьшении экрана, надписи плывут) (Прикреплю скрин)
2. Display: grid; (Но так как все надписи разного размера, то все верстка выглядит странно)(Так же прикреплю скрин)
3. Display: flex; (Та же проблема что и с grid)
   Как мне стилизировать их как на дизайне? (Скрин дизайна так же прикреплю)

Важный момент компоненты использую от UI библиотеки Mantine.[image: Верстка на гридах]

[image: Верстка на column]

[image: Дизайн]

Comment: У вас заголовок, описание и картинки не сходятся... Что именно у вас не получается? Застилить выведенные значения или есть проблемы с их рендером в реакте? Так же вы не указали, что ожидаете в итоге.

Comment: Мне нужно элементы с первой картинки стилизовать как на третей, что бы при изменении масштаба надписи не плыли как на второй картинке.

Comment: Тогда приведите код рендера и финальную разметку HTML со стилями